# Add Spark to Oozie shared lib

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, oozie

By default, Oozie shared lib directory provides libraries for Hive, Pig, and Map-Reduce. If I want to run Spark job on Oozie, it might be better to add Spark lib jars to Oozie's shared lib instead of copy them to app's lib directory. 
How can I add Spark lib jars (including spark-core and its dependencies) to Oozie's shared lib? Any comment / answer is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spark action is scheduled to be released with Oozie 4.2.0, even though the doc seems to be a bit behind. See related JIRA here :
[Oozie JIRA - Add spark action executor](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/OOZIE-1983)

Cloudera's release CDH 5.4 has it already though, see official doc here:
[CDH 5.4 oozie doc - Oozie Spark Action Extension](http://archive.cloudera.com/cdh5/cdh/5/oozie/DG_SparkActionExtension.html)

With the older version of Oozie, the jars could be shared with various approaches. The first approach may work the best. The complete listings anyway :

> Below are the various ways to include a jar with your workflow:
>
> Set oozie.libpath=/path/to/jars,another/path/to/jars in job.properties.
>
> > This is useful if you have many workflows that all need the same jar; you can put it in one place in HDFS and use it with many workflows. The jars will be available to all actions in that workflow. 
> >     There is no need to ever point this at the ShareLib location. (I see that in a lot of workflows.) Oozie knows where the ShareLib is and will include it automatically if you set oozie.use.system.libpath=true in job.properties.
>
> Create a directory named “lib” next to your workflow.xml in HDFS and put jars in there.
>
> > This is useful if you have some jars that you only need for one workflow. Oozie will automatically make those jars available to all actions in that workflow.
>
> Specify the  tag in an action with the path to a single jar; you can have multiple  tags.
>
> > This is useful if you want some jars only for a specific action and not all actions in a workflow.
> >     The downside is that you have to specify them in your workflow.xml, so if you ever need to add/remove some jars, you have to change your workflow.xml.
>
> Add jars to the ShareLib (e.g. /user/oozie/share/lib/lib_/pig)
>
> > While this will work, it’s not recommended for two reasons:
> >     The additional jars will be included with every workflow using that ShareLib, which may be unexpected to those workflows and users.
> >     When upgrading the ShareLib, you’ll have to recopy the additional jars to the new ShareLib.

quoted from Rober Kanter's blog here : [How-to: Use the ShareLib in Apache Oozie (CDH 5)](http://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2014/05/how-to-use-the-sharelib-in-apache-oozie-cdh-5/)

Comment: Hello Paul, currently I am trying to run Spark on Oozie with all needed jars compiled as a single uber jar that placed under Oozie workflow's lib directory and I think that it will be more convenient if Spark jars are provided by shared lib. Can we achieve this given our current Spark version?

Comment: Added some ideas in answer.

Comment: good news, Oozie 4.2.0 has been released
https://oozie.apache.org/docs/4.2.0/
Thank you, Paul