# how to add a jar file stored outside of the oozie project's ./lib folder?

Tags: oozie

I'm writing an oozie java action which has my custom code in a jar file in the job `./lib` folder.

I would also like to add to the classpath a jar in a folder external to my job (i.e. `/home/me/otherjars/spark-assembly.jar`).

The `./lib` folder gets added to the classpath automatically.  How can I get oozie to also add the external jar?

Answer (score 3):

The `oozie.libpath` property is definitely what you need. Please check...

- the [Oozie documentation](https://oozie.apache.org/docs/4.2.0/WorkflowFunctionalSpec.html#a17_HDFS_Share_Libraries_for_Workflow_Applications_since_Oozie_2.3)
- this [Oozie JIRA](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/OOZIE-748) about global/local scope for that property
- this [orphan thread](https://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/oozie-user/201308.mbox/%3CC8126251646CE8449326FBEB866972442C8D0BD5@turn-mail.turn.corp%3E) about *precedence order* (search for that
  phrase)
- this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30565546/add-spark-to-oozie-shared-lib) and this [other post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33715104/how-do-i-specify-multiple-libpath-in-oozie-job), for example

Answer (score 2):

The Bestway to use any custom Jars in Oozie useing, Once Oozie Sharedlib Installed in Cluster, you can mention place the Jar, in Sub Folder and pass the parameter

```
oozie.use.system.libpath = true
```

These will call Jar when every the Jobs are getting started.

Another option you can use, is adding Custom Path with UDF jar in hadoop_env.sh file under Hadoop ClassPath, These required your Hadoop restart to take effect, along with it also required you Custom JAR Path should be available in all the Nodes of Hadoop Cluster.